# Pump Messages During Long Operation

Tags: c#

> The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x1b2938 to
>   COM context 0x1b2aa8 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination
>   context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or
>   processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages.
>   This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead
>   to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating
>   continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment
>   (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as
>   CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running
>   operations.i used smtpClient class to sending mails

I want to send some emails with 3 kb/s connection speed but after 60 the error will raised.

Can anyone offer a best and complete solution in C#?

Comment: How are you sending your emails now?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a COM component to send emails.

You should use .Net's [`SmtpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class.